# Track freelancing work hours with client

Tags: time-management

I am looking for a time tracking and billing application that besides the obvious is as transparent as possible between the freelancer and the client.

For example: I login and start time tracker. If on the other side (through a web/desktop app) client logins. They should be able to see my work times, current status, current bill, etc.

Need a suggestion ASAP.

Comment: This would be a webapp, right? Are you looking for it to be hosted by a company, or do you want to host it yourself? What price are you looking for?

Comment: @Undo Web app portal but tracking in desktop, their hosting, preferably free. I guess an example would be PaymoPlus.

Comment: What do you need to track? Just working/not working?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't get it. But it is for my freelance work of course.